# What is the recommended way to handle TaskScheduler.UnobservedTaskException in GUI apps?

Tags: .net, vb.net, exception, task-parallel-library

For robustness I want to add a handler for TaskScheduler.UnobservedTaskException.
The handler does log Exception(s) inform the user and shutdown the app.

Does the following implementation make sense?
Is it OK in WPF to show a MessageBox or a Windows in this handler, or is this a bad idea because we are running in the finalizers of unobserved Tasks?

```
Private Sub TaskSheduler_UnobservedTaskException(sender As Object, e As UnobservedTaskExceptionEventArgs)
Static _wasUserInformed As Boolean = False

e.SetObserved()

'Trace all Exceptions
e.Exception.Flatten.Handle(Function(ex As Exception)
                               'TODO trace and log Exception
                               Debug.Print("UnobservedTaskException: {0}", ex.Message)
                               Return True
                           End Function)

If Not _wasUserInformed Then
    'Show root Exception 
    _wasUserInformed = True
    Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(Sub()
                                                   'MessageBox.Show(e.Exception.GetBaseException.Message)

                                                   Dim win As New UnexpectedExceptionWindow
                                                   win.UnexpectedException = e.Exception.GetBaseException
                                                   win.ShowDialog()

                                                   Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(Sub() Application.Current.Shutdown())
                                               End Sub)
End If
```

End Sub

[EDIT]
As a result of our discussion I came up with the following solution.

```
Private Sub TaskScheduler_UnobservedTaskException(sender As Object, e As UnobservedTaskExceptionEventArgs
                                                  ) Handles TaskScheduler.UnobservedTaskException
    Static _wasUserInformed As Boolean = False

    'Free the finalizer thread and execute on the UI thread to be able to inform user
    Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(Sub() LogException(e.Exception))
    e.SetObserved()
    If Not _wasUserInformed Then
        _wasUserInformed = True
        'Show first error 
        Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(Sub()
                                   NotifyUser(e.Exception)
                                   Application.Current.Shutdown()
                               End Sub)
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a very good question. As this event is running on the finalizer thread (I have confirmed this with Reflector) we cannot afford to block for an extend period of time. This would stop finalizer from being processed.

So the answer is: This is not a good design because the duration of the UI operation is unbounded.

A better solution would be to queue the processing to a new `Task` so that it runs on the thread-pool.

This answer depends on an implementation detail (finalizers being executed on a single thread and the event firing on the finalizer thread). But at least for apps supporting .NET 4.0 this answer is valid.

Comment: However, he is also calling Dispatcher.BeginInvoke, so the only thing really blocking the finalizer is the debug printing.  If he included that in the BeginInvoke action as well, there wouldn't be much in the way of blocking going on.